# Pagination doesn't show up on webpage

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I've gone through several examples, and none of them seem to change the outcome. What happens is the pagination just doesn't show up at all no matter how it's configured. when you inspect the page all you see the section for it but there are no links for pages. I'm not sure if this has to do with my server being ported into a noip hostname or if my databse isn't configured right to use this option

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sensor data</title>
</head>
<body>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 align="center">Voltage / Current sensor readings</h1>
<p align="center">These are our values coming from the sensors. They are being inserted into a database using a python script that automatically reads the serial port on the pi,
    that is connected to the Arduino.</p>
<p align="center">This script is reading every second uploading the data and then is being displayed within this table.</p>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "sensors";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " .$conn->connect_error);
}
$limit = 10;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page = $_GET["page"];} else {$page = 1;};
$start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM   sensorInfo ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT $start_from, $limit";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" align="center">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;Timestamp&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Solar Panel Voltage&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Solar Panel Current&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Solar Panel Power&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Turbine Voltage&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Turbine Current&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Turbine Power&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Grid Voltage&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Grid Current&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Grid Power&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Pump Voltage&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Pump Current&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;Pump Power&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%s </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td>
                <td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td>
                <td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td>
                <td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>",
                $row["time"], $row["sp_voltage"], $row["sp_current"], $row["sp_power"],
                $row["t_voltage"], $row["t_current"], $row["t_power"],
                $row["g_voltage"], $row["g_current"], $row["g_power"],
                $row["p_voltage"], $row["p_current"], $row["p_power"]);
        };
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<ul class = "pagination">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM sendorInfo";
    $results = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->num_rows;
    $total_records = $row[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
        echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i. "'>".$i."</a>";

    }
    ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you fetching as avove from sensorInfo  Table and in your pagination you are trying to fetch from sendorInfo table?

Comment: i think you have typo in second sql: `sendorInfo` maybe it should be `sensorInfo` like in first sql?

Comment: Oh yea, I rewrote that and saw that typo after the fact but even with the change it doesn't work

Comment: I have gone back over the code and renamed the variables for the sql and results and I also changed the fetch_assoc() to fetch_array and that seems to have fixed my issue